# File viewer with search filter by category and sub categories Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, documentviewer

I want to create a site running locally(localhost) which views files that are uploaded by authorized user. Using search filter by category and sub categories, all ebooks that are included in that sub categories will be shown. How to create this kind of search? Is there any module that will do exactly this one?

Ex, IT books---->programming books--->. Then it will display all programming books that are already been uploaded. When click to one of the programming books, it will display all the pages, like those in adobe reader. The concept is like that. how could i achieve this one? I'm having way too much problems searching for file viewer modules that will perfectly work. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Hi handy, check this url www.motorcityindubai.com/floorplans , do you want same like this???

Comment: hello bala, yup something like that. Any thing you can suggest?

Comment: Use Views to achieve this  and add the required fields & in Filter criteria add the fields and expose it,

Click Advanced-> Exposed form->exposed form style->Click Settings->Check Autosubmit. hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

In order to create the **file Directory** you can use the [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) and the [file_entity](https://drupal.org/project/file_entity) modules. I cannot get into details for this task. It needs some hours to explain if you are new to Drupal.

In order to **view/render any pdf** file you can use the [pdf](https://drupal.org/project/pdf) or [pdf_reader](https://drupal.org/project/pdf_reader) module that implement the [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) plugin (see a [live example of pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html)).

Comment: @HandyManny Did this answer solve your problem? If so please give some feedback (upvote, select as acceptable).